# How to disable autoplay for a embedded youtube video into a WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to disable autoplay for an embedded YouTube video that I have in a WebKit view. When I first open the view the video does not initially play but if i segue to another view in my navigation controller then segue back to that view the video starts to play fullscreen if it was previously started.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let youtubeURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/KUh2O8HylUM")
    let request = URLRequest(url: youtubeURL!)

    videoPlayer.load(request)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

All I need it to do is to prevent going fullscreen when I segue back to the view that this video is in. 

However, if the video has already been started and then I segue forward in the navigation controller then segue back it will open fullscreen and start playing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by just moving all of the code that I did have in `viewDidLoad()` into `viewWillAppear()`. This is what the functions look like now:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let youtubeURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/KUh2O8HylUM")
        let request = URLRequest(url: youtubeURL!)

        videoPlayer.load(request)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```